# Python requests library: use of json.dumps

Tags: python, python-3.x

Potential newbie question, but it has been bothering me since long time.

In a lot of Python tutorials, I see very similar snippets to post something to a REST API

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://api.blabla.com/v1'
token = '1234'

headers = { 
            'Authorization: f'Bearer {token}',
            'Content-Type: 'application/json'
          }
body = {
   'name': 'Test name'
}

my_response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(body)).json()
print(my_response)
```

The Request documentation says that the data object should receive a dict. In the above, the body is a dict already, so why is there a need to use `json.dump` because that essentially makes it a string (whereas documentation says it should be a dictionary).

So why shouldn't it be:

```
my_response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body).json()
```

On another note, the official Requests documentation also says we can pass the json parameter and in this example it would be (if we follow the documentation):

```
my_response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body).json()
```

But the JSON parameter should be a JSON object, so if we pass the body as such, it means we are passing a dict object to the JSON parameter which is not what the documentation says.

Note:

- The official [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) is using `data=json.dumps(body)`
- The W3schools [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_post.asp) is using `data=body`

Answer (score 3):

> `data` – the body to attach to the request. If a dictionary or list of
>   tuples `[(key, value)]` is provided, **form-encoding** will take
>   place.
>
> https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Request

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

If you pass a dict as `data`, it will be [*form-encoded*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). If you pass a dict as `json`, it will be JSON-serialised. The `json` argument is just a convenience shorthand for `data=json.dumps(body)`. Why many use the latter instead of the former… who knows.